# How to use ViewData with @Html.EditorFor for populating the text-box on page load in MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

```
@Html.Editor("Email", @ViewData["Email"])
```

I am using Editor and I'm able to populate the text-box but while validation error message doesn't appear  for it. I want to use EditorFor for strongly bonded code Please tell me any solution for this.

Comment: There isn't enough information here to really know what is going on, but the @ on your ViewData looks a bit strange, have you tried removing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't it possible for you to add this Field to passed `model`.If not then you will need to use `custom jquery validator` for this field.

Comment: This way I'm not able to  get the error message if text box left empty.

Comment: Please check using debugging that if there is any value in ViewData["Email"]

Comment: See, I'm saying error message is not displayed for text-box if left empty .

Comment: @Smokingmonkey why arent u using model as suggested by hutchonoid

Comment: Im using a different model in this view. Its for posting property by the user. Property model is different.

Comment: Isn't it possible for you to add this Field to passed model.If not then you will need to use custom jquery validator for this field.

Comment: It didn't come to my mind. I chose your first option and thw work is done. Thanks. :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't used any model in your view, simply create a model for email. If not you have to use simple jquery validations.

//Using model

```
public class EmailModel
{
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Email")]
        public string Email { get; set; }
}


@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email)

@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Email)
```

Hope this helps.